# Impose several restrictions on systems of eqns in R using systemfit package

Tags: r, econometrics

I'm estimating systems of simultaneous eqns in R, and trying to impose homogeneity and symmetry restrictions on the equations. I'm using the "systemfit" package. I've managed to impose one restriction on one of the eqns using 'restrict.matrix' (as you see from the example below). How do I impose all restrictions at the same time (restrict1, restrict2, restrict3 and so on)?

```
eqn1 <- s1 ~ p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + q
eqn2 <- s2 ~ p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + q
eqn3 <- s3 ~ p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 + q 
eqlist <- list (eqn1, eqn2, eqn3)

system_eqn <- systemfit(eqlist, method="SUR")

restrict1 <- "eq1_p1 + eq1_p1 + eq1_p3 + eq1_p4 = 0"
restrict2 <- "eq2_p1 + eq2_p1 + eq2_p3 + eq2_p4 = 0"
restrict3 <- "eq1_p2 - eq2_p1 = 0"

system_eqn_restrict <-(eqlist, method="SUR", restrict.matrix = restrict1)
```

Comment: See *micEconAIDS* package, the code of function `AIDSest` for example. Or alternatively use this function and do not worry about precise workings of systemfit, since this function will do what you want to do, i.e. estimate AIDS model.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I know the micEconAIDS package, which I've worked on before to estimate demand elasticities. This time I'm estimating supply elasticities using a translog cost function with the corresponding cost share eqns. I can't see that it's possible to use the micEconAIDS package. For example: the dependent variables in my case are value shares, as opposed to the AIDS model were the dependent variables are marketshares.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would be easier to demonstrate with some data because your restrictions seem curious, but the clue is in `restrict.matrix`, which works if it is a matrix.

```
restrictM <- matrix(c(0,2,0,1,1,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,
                      0,0,0,0,0,0,  0,2,0,1,1,0,  0,0,0,0,0,0,
                      0,0,1,0,0,0,  0,-1,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0),
                    byrow=TRUE, nrow=3, ncol=18)

system_eqn_restrict <-systemfit(eqlist, method="SUR", 
                                restrict.matrix = restrictM)
```

may work.

Personally I suspect you really want `0,1,1,1,1,0` rather than `0,2,0,1,1,0` twice in the matrix.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I added all the restrictions as a vector, and it worked: restrict <- c("eq1_p1+eq1_p2+eq1_p3=0", "eq2_p1+eq2_p2+eq2_p3=0") and then system_eqn_restrict <- systemfit(eqlist, method="SUR", restrict.matrix = restrict). Perfect, thanks!

Comment: @findus, it may be kind to mark the answer as being the answer to your question (green check mark)

Answer (score 3):

This is the solution that worked for me, and I'm posting it if anyone else get the same problem:

I added all the restrictions as a vector

```
restrict <- c("eq1_p1+eq1_p2+eq1_p3=0", "eq2_p1+eq2_p2+eq2_p3=0")
```

and then

```
system_eqn_restrict <- systemfit(eqlist, method="SUR", restrict.matrix = restrict)
```